# Decoherence and einselection model: Contradiction with two different explanations?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, decoherence, foundations

I am a little puzzled by einselection models. I followed those two papers ([Environment-induced superselection rules](https://journals.aps.org/prd/abstract/10.1103/PhysRevD.26.1862) [Decoherence, einselection, and the quantum origins of the classical](https://arxiv.org/abs/quant-ph/0105127)) to understand it and I end up in some contradiction with two different explanations.

**Global summary of decoherence theory with a spin measurement example.**

We have a system $S$ (spin here) to be measured, an apparatus $A$ (also spin to simplify explanation) and the environment $E$ around. The goal is to describe a measurement using only unitary operations. Basically, if I assume the state is initially the following:

$$ \left( \alpha |0\rangle + \beta |1\rangle \right) \otimes |A_0\rangle \otimes |E_0\rangle \tag{A}$$

What happens is that first, system and apparatus get entangled and we get (I assume for simplicity that all the state I write in a given tensor product space are orthogonal to each other).

$$ \left( \alpha |0 A_0 \rangle + \beta |1 A_1\rangle \right) \otimes |E_0\rangle \tag{B}$$

The measurement process is not yet finished. Indeed we need to kill the coherences in the basis $|i A_i\rangle$. It will be done by entanglement with the environment:

$$ \alpha |0 A_0 E_0 \rangle + \beta |1 A_1 E_1\rangle \tag{C}$$

Tracing out the environment, we get the density matrix for $S-A$ that is:

$$\rho_{SA}^f= |\alpha|^2 |0 A_0 \rangle \langle 0 A_0 |+ |\beta|^2  |1 A_1 \rangle \langle 1 A_1 | \tag{D}$$

We only used unitaries and we get the good final density matrix for the system-apparatus state. The point is then to specify the properties of the Hamiltonian that allow for such evolution.

**System-apparatus correlation as explained in [Decoherence, einselection, and the quantum origins of the classical](https://arxiv.org/abs/quant-ph/0105127) or in section II of [Environment-induced superselection rules](https://journals.aps.org/prd/abstract/10.1103/PhysRevD.26.1862) (with different notations)**

In this paper they give an example of Hamiltonian allowing to do the spin-apparatus correlations. Basically the evolution is the one done by a CNOT. Assuming no bare hamiltonian for $S$ or $A$, this evolution can be done via:

$$H_{SA}=g |1 \rangle \langle 1 | \otimes |A_- \rangle \langle A_- | \tag{1}$$

For an interaction time $t=\frac{\pi}{g}$, where $|A_- \rangle$ is the $-$ state of the Bloch sphere: $|A_- \rangle=\frac{|A_0 \rangle-|A_1 \rangle}{\sqrt{2}}$

Thus, using this Hamiltonian, we can have the dynamic $(A) \rightarrow (B)$. We now need to explain the second evolution (correlation with environment), i.e evolution $(B) \rightarrow (C)$.

**Correlation with environment as explained in [Environment-induced superselection rules](https://journals.aps.org/prd/abstract/10.1103/PhysRevD.26.1862)**

Here, I am a little bit more general and I do not assume any specific dimensions for the systems (I want to be as close as possible from this more general paper).
I define $\phi=S+A$, I express the total Hamiltonian (on $\phi, E$) as:

$$H=H_{\phi} + H_E + H_{\phi E}$$

Where:

$$ H_{\phi}=\sum_i \phi_i |\phi_i \rangle \langle \phi_i | \tag{2}$$
$$ H_{E}=\sum_i e_i |E_i \rangle \langle E_i | \tag{3}$$
$$ H_{\phi E}=\sum_{i,j} \lambda_{i,j} |\phi_i E_j \rangle \langle \phi_i E_j | \tag{4}$$

We notice that the interaction is particular in the sense that it is in the same basis as the bare hamiltonians.

Then, we can show that starting from a state $|\psi(0) \rangle=\sum_i \alpha_i |\phi_i \rangle \otimes \sum_j \beta_j |E_j \rangle$, we end up in a state $|\psi(t) \rangle$ after a time $t$.

Tracing out the environment, the final density matrix on $\phi$ is:

$$\rho_{\phi}=\sum_{i,j} \rho_{ij} |\phi_i \rangle \langle \phi_j | \tag{5}$$

And in short: $\rho_{i \neq j}$ are terms that oscillates and vanishes in average: this evolution killed the coherences (I skip the details to get to the point).

**What confuses me:**

We notice that with this mechanism we killed the coherence in the basis of the bare hamiltonian $H_{\phi}$. It would correspond to the basis $|0 A_+ \rangle, |0 A_- \rangle, |1 A_+ \rangle, |1 A_- \rangle$ of the example. And this is contradictory with the fact during this process we must kill the coherences in the basis: $|0A_0\rangle, |0A_1\rangle, |1 A_0\rangle, |1 A_1\rangle$.

Furthermore, the general case is supposed to be a generalisation (including the environmental correlation) of the first case I presented. Indeed it is explicitly written in [Environment-induced superselection rules](https://journals.aps.org/prd/abstract/10.1103/PhysRevD.26.1862):

> The subject of the following section (section II) is to introduce the idea of the environment-induced super-selection rules on a simple, exactly soluble example of interacting two-state quantum systems. Section III explores in a more general way conditions under which superselection rules may be induced.

(section II is what I presented first, section III what I presented after). Then it seems he tries to be more general just after and for me the two explanations are not compatible.

How can I reconciliate the two explanations ?

Comment: @ChiralAnomaly Thank you for your answer. For me the second situation is a generalization of the first one (the first one being an example). Indeed at the very end of page 1863 of "Environment-induced superselection rules" he explicitly says: "The subject of the following section is to introduce the idea of the environment-induced
super-selection rules on a simple, exactly soluble example of interacting two-state quantum systems. Section III explores in a more general way conditions
under which superselection rules may be induced".

Comment: And the section II of this document is actually exactly the same as the CNOT measurement I presented. Thus it seems section III is a generalization of it. But for me the generalization doesn't fit this particular case because of the reason I wrote in my question. Thus I am super confused

Comment: @ChiralAnomaly you are write, it is a typo. It is now edited. (I retagged properly the equations)